# VB.NET: how to only take numerical values from a label when defining it as a variable

Tags: vb.net, function, variables, label

I cant take just the number from my label (called `lblCps`, label contains `Cps Value: 0`
I want to just take the `0` from the Label and use it as a variable in the rest of my code, but I can't figure out how to not include the `Cps value:` when I try to define it in: `Public cps As integer = lbl`

Is there any function that lets me only take numerical values when I call it as a variable or only take values after the ":" or any specific character?

Comment: No, no, no! DO NOT use the contents of a `Label` as input for anything... EVER! `Labels` are read-only, i.e. the user cannot enter data directly into a `Label`. As such, YOU must have put anything it contains into it in the first place. If you need to use that data for something other than displaying in the `Label`, use the data from the source, not the `Label`. If you need to assign it to a variable until you need it then do that. `Labels` are there to display data, not store it.

Comment: If what you're displaying in the `Label` was constructed from a number in the first place then you should be using that original number and there's no question to begin with. If you get the text "as is" then you need to extract the number from that original `String`, so the `Label` is still irrelevant. You can use `Val` to get numbers from the head of a `String` but anything else requires standard string manipulation, like extracting any other substring. You can use `Split`, `IndexOf`, a `Regex` or whatever you like. It's just string manipulation and nothing specific to numbers.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the data I'm trying to display isn't meant to be interacted with by the user directly so that's why I chose a label. But what I think your trying to say is that instead of using the lable to store the data and extract the number from the variable to use in the code, it would be better to create a variable then display that variable onto the label?

Comment: That's basically it. The `Label` is for display to the user only.

Comment: @jmcilhinney O.k thanks I'll try it that way

Comment: How EXACTLY do you get the data in the first place?

Comment: @jmcilhinney from a function I made, but that is unrealted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no custom function which will do this for you.
You can split the text by space and then check each word if it is numeric using the IsNumeric function. Or you can split based on ":" and then take check if the second part is numeric.
Use the Split function on the string

Comment: What function would I use for splitting based on the ":"

Comment: You can use the split itself. lblCps.Text.Split(":"). If the format is always text : number, then you can use Integer.Parse(lblCps.Text.Split(":")(1).Trim()) to get the number directly. But it is better to check the split() result is greater than 1 before directly using the index like Split(":")(1)